# Maven: dependency on a third party jar not in central

Tags: android, maven, jar

I'm mavenizing [RoboBillingLibrary](https://github.com/christopherperry/RoboBillingLibrary) and I've got a dependency on [Amazon's in-app purchasing library](https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/in-app-purchasing.html) that's not in [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/). What's the proper way to add the dependency (without submitting it to central myself)?

I [have already installed it locally](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html), and this works fine for me, but not so well for anyone who wants to use my library. Also, I'd like to deploy RoboBillingLibrary to central and this dependency is preventing me from doing so. I tried

```
mvn clean install
```

from the parent directory just to see if I could install it and it complains:

> Could not find artifact com.amazon:in-app-purchasing:jar:1.0.3 in
>
> central

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mvn install:install-file -Dfile=in-app-purchasing-1.0.3.jar -DgeneratePom=true -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=1.0.3 -DgroupId=in-app-purchasing -DartifactId=in-app-purchasing`

change values according or use a pom file -DpomFile=pom.xml

Comment: I doubt you can submit an artifact that depends on something not in the repo

Comment: I already installed it locally. I'm trying to generate an apklib, and install that into my local maven repo, and I can't because of the Amazon dependency.

Comment: why it fails if you have amazon artifact in your local repo?

Comment: The -DgeneratePom=true was the piece I was missing. I now appear to be missing something else. I did a 'mvn clean install' in the main folder, and everything installed, except I looked in the local repo and there's no jar file for RoboBillingLibrary, only for DungeonsRedux.